# Is there any way to reduce map quest server hits, while performing zooming

Tags: android, zooming, mapquest

I would like to ask is there a way i can reduce the number of hits to the map quest server while zooming the map in android. I am using map quest Android SDK. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official method or control to reduce the number of zoom levels used by the user. But you could create a zoom control that has only a few zoom levels on it that helps the user get to parcel, street, city, or state zoom levels directly. I've used a similar control on my issue test page (using a Leaflet map with MapQuest plugins) for years.